# Access via IAM role to EKS cluster

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, amazon-eks

Please help to understand why I receiving

> error: You must be logged in to the server (Unauthorized)

I have created an empty EKS host and created inside role by manual :

```
eksctl create iamidentitymapping \
  --cluster eks-cluster \
  --arn arn:aws:iam::account_number:role/eks_test_full_role \
  --username admin \
  --group system:masters
```

and it's working

```
eksctl get iamidentitymapping --cluster eks-cluster
ARN                                             USERNAME                GROUPS
arn:aws:iam::account_number:role/eks_test_full_role                     admin                   system:masters
arn:aws:iam::account_number:role/eks-cluster-eks-workers-iam-role   system:node:{{EC2PrivateDNSName}}   system:bootstrappers,system:nodes
```

After I have created IAM user which can assume created role with all required permissions

```
aws sts assume-role --role-arn arn:aws:iam::account_number:role/eks_test_full_role --role-session-name test
{
    "Credentials": {
        "AccessKeyId": "",
        "SecretAccessKey": "",
        "SessionToken": "",
        "Expiration": "2021-02-04T10:24:59Z"
    },
    "AssumedRoleUser": {
        "AssumedRoleId": "Role_id:test",
        "Arn": "arn:aws:sts::account_number:assumed-role/eks_test_full_role/test"
    }
}
```

What step I have missed to have it works?

P.S. my role and rolebinding

```
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: Role
metadata:
  namespace: dev
  name: get-pods
rules:
- apiGroups: [""]
  resources: ["pods"]
  verbs: ["get", "watch", "list"]

apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: RoleBinding
metadata:
  name: get-pods-bind
  namespace: dev
subjects:
- kind: User
  name: admin
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
roleRef:
  kind: Role
  name: get-pods
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to edit the aws-auth configmap and allow this different IAM user to access the cluster. Something like below:

```
1. kubectl edit cm aws-auth -n kube-system
```

2. Add the below config and edit the username placeholders and account-id placeholder. If `mapusers` already exists, then just add a new entry to it starting with `-` in the next line:

```
mapUsers: |
    - userarn: arn:aws:iam::<account-id>:user/<name of IAM user>
      username: <name of IAM user>
      groups:
        - system:masters
```